# How to send e-mails on users defined date and time with PHP?

Tags: php, email, cron, appointment

I have an agenda system where you can schedule events and appointments and choose a date and an hour for each appointment/event.

The user will choose to receive a reminder to its appointment, the reminder can be 5 minutes before the event starts, 1 hour before the event starts, 2 days before the event starts, etc...

So, if an user's appointment is scheduled to Today at 10:00 PM and the reminder is "10m before", I'll need to make php send an e-mail to the user at 09:50 PM. For now, I'll have to make reminders to be sent 5m, 10m, 30m, 1h, 2h, 5h, 12h, 1d and 2d before the event starts.

How can I make PHP send e-mails on users defined time?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to separate the system into two applications:

- The application users use to schedule things.
- The back-end application that sends the emails.

The first application should write the scheduled items to a database and the back-end application would read from the database and send the emails.

One way you may be able to structure this is to have the scheduled items stored something like this:

```
ScheduledItems
--------------
ID (int)
Title (string)
EventTime (datetime)
ReminderType (int)
ReminderSent (bool)
```

The `ReminderType` might be a foreign key to a lookup list of the reminders you mentioned:

> 5m, 10m, 30m, 1h, 2h, 5h, 12h, 1d and 2d before the event starts

The second application would then be scheduled via cron to run probably every 5 minutes (since that's the most granular reminder time) and scan for `ScheduledItems` where `ReminderSent` is false (hasn't been sent yet) and `EventTime` minus some timespan value in the `ReminderType` lookup table is less than or equal to the current datetime.

For each record it finds, send the reminder and update `ReminderSent` to true.